# Controller function to switch to a new html page in AngularJS for Android Application

Tags: android, angularjs

My index.html file contail:

> ```
>  <body background="img\loginback.jpg" ng-controller="SignInCtrl" >  <button ng-click='signIn()'>SignUp</button> </body>
> ```

and my app.js contains:

> angular.module('StatusLogger', ['ionic']) .controller('SignInCtrl',
>   function($scope, $location) {
>        $scope.signIn = function() {
>       $location.path('home.html');   };  })

But the home.html is not called.
Please help me, where i am doing mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console of your browser? Where are you setting the ng-app attribute in your HTML?

Comment: I am not using this code for browser application. I am developing android application using AngularJS on Ionic framework. I am not getting any error.

Comment: An Android application built using Ionic is still a browser based application for nearly all intents and purposes. Are you saying that you don't have a console to work with that displays errors? Or you do and you don't see any there?

Comment: I am using Ionic through command prompt and edit code using notepad. It does not show any error or message on command prompt. I am new to this framework and technology. May u please help me to navigate from one html to another using AngularJS in android application using Ionic Framework.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't provided enough detail for someone to help you debug the problem. You should develop in an environment that provides a console that reports errors. Ionic is just a framework that allows you to package and compile HTML/CSS/JavaScript. You should be able to find a way to work in a browser like Chrome or Firefox, which will provide a robust development/debugging environment for you to work in. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use the **$apply()**. Try again with code below:

*HTML*

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="SignInCtrl">   
    <button ng-click="signIn()">SignUp</button>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
function SignInCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.signIn = function() {
        $scope.$apply( $location.path( 'http://google.com' ) );
    };  
}
```

I hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This also not worked for me. Can you please tell me how to navigate from one html to another using AngularJS in android application.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="StatusLogger" ng-controller="SignInCtrl">   
    <button ng-click="signIn()">SignUp</button>
</body>
```

**contoller**

```
angular.module('StatusLogger', ['ionic'])
    .controller('SignInCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
        $scope.signIn = function () {
            $location.path('home.html');
        };
    });
```